# Postgres Unlogged Table With Index Vs Without Index Performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

How is the read / write performance with the unlogged table different from index and non-index?

Answer (score 5):

`UNLOGGED` has no impact on the speed of `SELECT` statements, but it makes all data modifying statements faster, because no WAL has to be written.

Tables without any index are very fast for `INSERT`, because rows are just stuffed into the first best block of the “heap” where there is room. Indexes are up to an order of magnitude more expensive to modify, because the order has to be preserved.

The question of `LOGGED`/`UNLOGGED` is independent from the question of indexed/not indexed. Both `UNLOGGED` and not indexed speed up data modifications.